# html5 canvas: overlapping paths not filling correctly

Tags: html5-canvas

strange issue with HTML5 canvas: I am trying to draw one shape inside another.  The outer shape is blue and the inner one red, but the end result is that both shapes end up red.  If I step through the code, I can see the blue shape rendered correctly, but then the red shape renders over the blue one, even though it's smaller.  Probably a problem with BeginPath/EndPath stuff, but I've seemingly tried every combination with no luck.  I have lots more shapes to draw after this one, so I need to figure out how to correctly begin/end a shape before I resume work.  Any help is appreciated.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () {
                var drawingCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');

                // Is element in the DOM and does browser support canvas
                if (drawingCanvas && drawingCanvas.getContext) {
                    // Init drawing context
                    var InfieldColor = "#BDB76B";
                    var OutfieldColor = "#F5F5F5";

                    var iGrassLen = Math.min(drawingCanvas.width, drawingCanvas.height) * 0.7;
                    var iRad = iGrassLen * 1.475;
                    var iAng = -60 * Math.PI / 180;
                    var iptInfBez0x = iRad * Math.cos(iAng);
                    var iptInfBez0y = -(iRad * Math.sin(iAng));

                    iAng = -30 * Math.PI / 180;
                    var iptInfBez1x = iRad * Math.cos(iAng);
                    var iptInfBez1y = -(iRad * Math.sin(iAng));
                    var iInfieldLen = (iGrassLen * (88 / 124));

                    var iBaseLen = iInfieldLen / 12;

                    //this is the relative offset between Dixon infield and outfield
                    var iOutfieldLen = iGrassLen * (282 / 124)

                    //bezier control points for outfield circle
                    iRad = iOutfieldLen * 1.31;
                    iAng = -60 * Math.PI / 180;
                    var iptOutBez0x = iRad * Math.cos(iAng);
                    var iptOutBez0y = -(iRad * Math.sin(iAng));

                    iAng = -30 * Math.PI / 180;
                    var iptOutBez1x = iRad * Math.cos(iAng);
                    var iptOutBez1y = -(iRad * Math.sin(iAng));

                    var iHRLen0 = (340 * iInfieldLen / 90) * 1.025;      //iInfieldLen = 90 feet. (plus a fudge factor)
                    var iHRLen1 = (370 * iInfieldLen / 90) * 1.025;
                    var iHRLen2 = (400 * iInfieldLen / 90) * 1.025;

                    var iMoundWid = iInfieldLen / 10;

                    var context = drawingCanvas.getContext('2d');

                    context.fillStyle = "#FFFF00";
                    context.fillRect(0, 0, drawingCanvas.width, drawingCanvas.height);

                    context.beginPath;
                    context.moveTo(0, 0);
                    context.lineTo(iGrassLen, 0);
                    context.bezierCurveTo(iptInfBez1x, iptInfBez1y, iptInfBez0x, iptInfBez0y, 0, iGrassLen); // bezier curve
                    context.lineTo(0, 0);
                    context.closePath();
                    context.fillStyle = "blue";
                    context.fill();
                    context.lineWidth = 1;
                    context.strokeStyle = "black";
                    context.stroke();

                    //infield rectangle
                    context.beginPath;
                    context.rect(0, 0, iInfieldLen - (iBaseLen / 4), iInfieldLen - (iBaseLen / 4));
                    context.closePath;
                    context.fillStyle = "red";
                    context.fill();
                    context.lineWidth = 1;
                    context.strokeStyle = "black";
                    context.stroke();

                }
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
context.beginPath;
...
context.closePath;
```

You forgot `()`. Without that, these are just discarded references to a function, not calls to it.

Comment: thanks much from a javascript newbie, I missed that problem. I understand that this is syntactically correct, but is there an editor that will show this as a potential error?  I'm coming from developing in .NET languages in Visual Studio, and I'm finding the lack of help from the IDE on syntax problems frustrating while developing javascript code.

Comment: [jslint](http://jslint.com/). Although you have to turn off a lot of Crockford's more dogmatic and questionable rules (eg one-var-per-fuction) to get to the real problems. It also finds a missing semicolon on the `var iOutfieldLen` line.

Comment: thanks much, that website is will shave hours off my javascript development time!