# HTML5 Canvas | Nuances with .moveTo() and .fillI()

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, bezier

I'm trying to fill a face I drew in canvas (made of quadratic and bezier curves) with green. After the first bezier curve, I use a moveTo and have it direct to the endpoint of the curve (yes, a bit redundant) before creating the next curve (a quadratic curve). After I made the whole face, I used fill. The face fills some of the face with green, but leaves a white triangle in the middle. When I remove the redundant moveTo() I mentioned earlier, however the entire shape fills with green as intended. Can someone explain this?

**My thoughts/attempts:**

- Because the triangle's points are the same as the points between two intersecting curves, I first thought it was because the curves weren't touching, and went back and fixed that.
- moveTo() creates a 'new point' above the endpoint of the bezier Curve so it's really that new point and the next curve that are intersecting instead of the bezier curve and the next curve?

**Consulted:**

I looked at Mozilla Developer Network's Canvas Tutorial explanation of moveTo(), and searched here using keywords like 'moveTo()' '.fill()' 'adjacent curves' 'adjacent bezier curves.' I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812687/html5-canvas-overlapping-paths-not-filling-correctly), but it wasn't exactly what I was looking for.

**HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>FACE</title>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id = 'canvas' height = '900' width = '900'></canvas>
    <script src = 'face.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript Code Here**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); <br>
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');<br><br>
function greenHeadFront()
{
    var rightHeadx = 110.5;
    var rightHeady = 80;
    var leftHeadx = 40.5;
    var leftHeady = 80;

    context.moveTo(leftHeadx, leftHeady);
    context.bezierCurveTo(leftHeadx+6, leftHeady-40, rightHeadx-6, rightHeady-40, rightHeadx, rightHeady);        //TOP OF HEAD
    context.moveTo(rightHeadx, rightHeady);
    context.quadraticCurveTo( 115 , 100  ,  rightHeadx, rightHeady+30);//RIGHT CHEEK
    context.bezierCurveTo (100 , 114, 129, 152,   75, 131); //RIGHT CHIN
    context.moveTo(leftHeadx,leftHeady);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(35, 100, leftHeadx, leftHeady+30);//LEFT CHEEK
    context.bezierCurveTo(53, 120, 23, 148, 75, 131); //LEFT CHIN
    context.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,156,0)';
    context.fill();
    context.stroke(); 
}

greenHeadFront();
```

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing : do *not* use hard-coded constant, this might be a source of troubles.
Another thing, do not hesitate to use context transforms to simplify your drawing code.
Lastly, your code will be much easier to (re)use if you are using simple to understand parameters : for instance you could provide the bounding box's top-left's x,y and width/height of the figure to draw.

So below i wrote untested code just to show you how could re-write your drawing code more clearly.
The idea is to translate to top-left corner of the figure, then scale the context so you can use only coordinates in between 0.0 and 1.0 to later do your draw.
Again, do not hesitate to name your constants in the function, and you might later elect some constant as function parameter.

```
function greenHeadFront(x, y, width, height )
{
    context.save();
    context.translate(x,y);
    context.scale(width, height);
    // !! required !!
    context.beginPath();
    // now all coordinates are beetween (0,0) (top-left) 
    //     and (1.0,1.0) (bottom-right)
    var cheekHeight = 0.1 ; 
    context.moveTo(0.5, 1 - cheekHeight); // move to center middle point.
    context.quadraticCurveTo( ??);//RIGHT CHEEK 
    context.bezierCurveTo (??); //RIGHT CHIN
    context.bezierCurveTo(  ?? );  //TOP OF HEAD
    context.bezierCurveTo(??); //LEFT CHIN
    context.quadraticCurveTo(??);//LEFT CHEEK
    context.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,156,0)';
    context.fill();
    context.strokeStyle='#000';
    context.lineWidth=0.01;
    context.stroke();
    context.strokeRect(0,0,1,1);  // for debug
    context.restore();
}

greenHeadFront( ?? );
```

Now for your triangle issue, it's the expected behavior : each time you call moveTo, you are creating a new sub-path, so your figure is now built out of several sub-path that will all be filled when you call to fill(). And those sub-paths do not cover all the surface you'd like to be filled.

Comment: Thanks! I normally use a grid to help me draw, but omitted it on here for the sake of brevity.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas paths are dependent on the direction the path is drawn (either clockwise or counter-clockwise). Here's a [little info](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/audiovideo/conceptual/html-canvas-guide/DrawingLinesandShapes/DrawingLinesandShapes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010542-CH3-SW6) about how drawing the different ways affects areas that are filled.

Also a bit unrelated but I believe you are missing calls to the `context.beginPath();` and `context.closePath();` methods to signify the beginning and end of a shape. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I'm still a little confused about how this knowledge applies to this case, however :c For the green face, the top of the head (bezier curve) and all of the right side of the face are going in a clockwise direction (the bezier goes right, the right side of the face goes top to bottom), so I'm confused why there is white space anywhere near that region, and why the white space isn't just a white line connecting the other two points (intersections where there is a clash between clockwise and counterclockwise).

Comment: I also tried applying the winding rule, starting with a point P in the white triangle and just drawing a straight path out of the face so that the path only intersects one side of the face (one clockwise or counterclockwise path), giving it a non-zero winding number, meaning it _should_ be filled, but I'm probably applying the rule wrong, and was wondering if you could also clarify this part of your link. Thanks so much! Sorry for all the additional pressing.